# Xamarin Forms : byte[] to image , save the iamge in device and open it again

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maui, barcode

```
byte[] imageAsBytes = (byte[].obj.RawData);
var stream = new MemoryStream(imageAsBytes);
image = ImageSource.FromStream(() => stream);

string filename = "myimage.png";
string root = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal);
string filePath = Path.Combine(root, filename);
using (FileStream fileStream = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
     await fileStream.WriteAsync(imageData, 0, imageData.Length);
}
var filepath = await SaveImageAsync(imageAsBytes, filename);

 if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filepath))
 {
     Debug.WriteLine($"File path is{filepath}");
     Launcher.OpenAsync(new OpenFileRequest
     {
         File = new ReadOnlyFile(filepath)
     });
 }
```

in this i can able to open the image but it is not visible in the device failed to open the image

Comment: What is `obj`?  Where is `imageData”` defined?

Comment: The obj is from the barcode reader I checked it it is not null and image data is imageasBytes = imagedata  @Jason

Comment: `in this i can able to open the image but it is not visible in the device failed to open the image` this is a blanket statement, you need to provide relevant issue/bug you are facing

Comment: am trying to scan the BarCode And Convert it into a bytes array. 
now I am trying to reproduce the same image that I scanned in the bar-code  and save it into an image file Like PNG/JPGE etc 
And trying to open the same image n my Xamarin Forms app @FreakyAli